# Sql Trigger condition check not working

Tags: mysql, triggers

I am creating a checking condition for a field in my data base. In the table called student, I have a field for Gender. This field should accept one of two values 'M' or 'F'. I have created a trigger like so:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `test_before_insert` BEFORE INSERT ON `student`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.Gender<>'M' OR NEW.Gender<>'F' THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '12345'
            SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'should be M or F';
    END IF;
END$$   
DELIMITER ;
```

The trigger is created but the field 'Gender' won't accept any values including M or F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition is wrong. It is always true. use

```
IF NEW.Gender not in ('M', 'F') THEN
```

or use

```
IF NEW.Gender<>'M' AND NEW.Gender<>'F' THEN
```

Comment: thanks , it works now.  Why doesn't the <> work in my case?

Comment: Because you have 2 conditions in your `if` and one of them is true or the other

Comment: You could also use `and` instead of `or` in your query